# Dropbox setup/authentication issue on Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am following all the instructions followed on the getting started [Dropbox page](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android) but, I get a red mark on AndroidAuthSession, and AppKeyPair and, when i try to import them using:

```
import com.dropbox.client2.android.AndroidAuthSession;
import com.dropbox.client2.session.AppKeyPair;
```

I get a "symbol not found" on AndroidAuthSession and Session.
I have imported all the library files: Libs/dropbox-sync-sdk-android.jar and, placed the appropriate .so files: app/src/main/jniLibs/*
which were found in the sdk file download from their site. Could someone help resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox provides two different Android SDKs with different capabilities and different classes. The code you have is for the Android Core SDK:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/android

However, the files you mention, dropbox-sync-sdk-android.jar and the .so files, are from the Sync SDK:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/sdks/android

If you did mean to use the Core SDK, install that instead, from the first link above. Or, if you did mean to use the Sync SDK, the tutorial is here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/android